# SAP GUI ID is changing

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

I want to do a mass upload of data in SAP GUI, say update the price on 100 PO's. I can write a macro using VB Script and run it through the SAP GUI script recording and playback option, but while doing it the macro gets stuck as the SAP GUI Id gets changed from time to time.

Is there a fix for this?

Example code:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "me22n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").text = "44101194"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-KONNR[17,0]").text = "46062154"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[18,0]").text = "10"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[18,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[18,0]").caretPosition = 3
For i = 0 To 3
  session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[9,0]").text = "29.4"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[9,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[9,0]").caretPosition = 14
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[21]").press
For i = 0 To 3
  session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[18]").press
  session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").text = "44101195"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-KONNR[17,0]").text = "46062154"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[18,0]").text = "10"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[18,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[18,0]").caretPosition = 3
For i = 0 To 3
  session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[9,0]").text = "29.4"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[9,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0015/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[9,0]").caretPosition = 14
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Answer (score 1):

do you use any specific transaction? by the way delete the part until maximize at first. And put this

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")   
 Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 
    Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 
    Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
```